# Can someone explain some things that I am unsure of in this text?

Tags: phenomenology, husserl

This is a passage from a summary on Husserl’s philosophy from https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/husserl/

This is on the last paragraph of section 6:

This deep-structure of intentional consciousness comes to light in the course of what Husserl calls the “phenomenological reduction” (Husserliana, vol. XIII, pp. 432 ff), which uses the method of epoché in order to make coherent sense, in terms of the essential horizon-structure of consciousness, of the transcendence of objective reality. The most global form of epoché is employed when this reality in total is bracketed. There is still something left at this point, though, which must not, and cannot, be bracketed: the temporal flow of one’s “present” experience, constituted by current retentions and original impressions. These recurrent temporal features of the horizon-structure of consciousness cannot be meaningfully doubted. They provide a kind of hýle for “inner perception” and corresponding reflective judgements, but it is a very special kind of hýle: one that is a proper part of the “perceived” item and does not get conceptually “formed” in the course of perception (reflecting the fact that unlike spatio-temporal objects, lived experiences “do not adumbrate themselves”; cf. Husserliana, vol. III/1, p. 88). Hence, there is no epistemically problematic gap between experience and object in this case, which therefore provides an adequate starting point for the phenomenological reduction, that may now proceed further by using holistic justification strategies. After all, intentional consciousness has now been shown to be coherently structured at its phenomenologically deepest level.

In the last two sentences:

Why does he say that there are no epistemically problematic gap between experience and the object?

Why would this provide an adequate starting point for the phenomenological reduction?

What are these ‘holistic justification strategies’?

I don’t understand what the last sentence has got to do with the previous one?

Comment: The indexical temporal feature consisting of retentions, original impressions and protentions as a proper part of any singular *intentional* object situated in the lifeworld's horizon-structure of consciousness cannot be formed in the course of any unavoidably theory-laden perception simply by our physiologically seemingly advanced and fast edge-detection object classification & identification learning capability, thus the said *thetic* or *positing* nature as the underlying hýle at the deepest level *felicitously* delineates how consciousness experiences object without any epistemic gap...